# How to get endpoint path in ChannelInterceptor with spring boot stomp?

Tags: spring-boot, stomp

I am new in stomp use spring boot 2.1.2.RELEASE. I have multi endpoint and config a `ChannelInterceptor` to get some info.

```java
@Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        registry.addEndpoint("/endpoint1")
                .addInterceptors(new IpHandshakeInterceptor())
                .setAllowedOrigins(origin)
                .withSockJS();

        registry.addEndpoint("/endpoint2")
                .addInterceptors(new IpHandshakeInterceptor())
                .setAllowedOrigins(origin)
                .withSockJS();
        // other andpoint
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
        registration.interceptors(myChannelInterceptor());
    }
```

All endpoint use `myChannelInterceptor`(actually, i want endpoint use its own ChannelInterceptor), i want do thing in `ChannelInterceptor` by endpoint path.

```java
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
  if (endpoint.equals("endpoint1")) {
  } else if (endpoint.equals("endpoint2")) {
  }
}
```

How can i get `endpoint` info in `ChannelInterceptor`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

1. In class IpHandshakeInterceptor write value to attributes map:

   ```
    @Override
    public boolean beforeHandshake(ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest, ServerHttpResponse serverHttpResponse, WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler, Map<String, Object> map) throws Exception {
        if (serverHttpRequest instanceof ServletServerHttpRequest) {
            ServletServerHttpRequest servletRequest = (ServletServerHttpRequest) serverHttpRequest;
            HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
            //add value to session attributes
            map.put("endpoint", servletRequest.getURI().getPath());
        }
        // ... your logic ...
        return true;
    }
   ```
2. In your myChannelInterceptor read value from session attributes:

   ```
    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(final Message<?> message, final MessageChannel channel) throws AuthenticationException {
        final StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
        String endpoint=accessor.getSessionAttributes().get("endpoint").toString();
        // ... your logic ...
        return message;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the destination topic and also user object (if you populated it earlier) in the SUBSCRIBE command like this:

```
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    StompHeaderAccessor accessor = MessageHeaderAccessor.getAccessor(message, StompHeaderAccessor.class);
    if (StompCommand.CONNECT.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
        // authenticate request and populate user object
    }
    if (StompCommand.SUBSCRIBE.equals(accessor.getCommand())) {
        authorizeRequest(accessor.getUser(), accessor.getDestination());
    }
    return message;
}
```